# SDN neo4j 3.0 Release Index Strategy

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Since I updated from RC1 to RELEASE I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No index name allowed on label based indexes
```

which means **@Index** will now default to Label and not Simple indexing.

How do I specify the labels for each **@NodeEntity** ?
From [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/ExULhn1wRio) I think I should use **@Labels** but is this official ?

Considering issue [DATAGRAPH-433](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-433) will unique indexes use the old index strategy?

The spring data neo4j documentation doesn't offer any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either just remove the `indexName` from your `@Indexed` annotations.

Or you add `@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.SIMPLE)` for the old indexes.

You have to manually set that for unique indexes too. I have a blog post in writing for SDN 3.0. To be published some time tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the `indexType.SIMPLE` after looking through github for SDN 3, but since it's deprecated I wanted to not use it. After some more information from you, after I asked the question, I decided to skip SDN and just create my own DAO classes since I have more freedom to manipulate relationships. But there are pros and cons for each approach :)

Comment: How's the blog coming along?