# Index name for class java.lang.String name rel: false idx: true must differ from the default name (SDN 3.0)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

After upgrading from SDN 2.3.4 to 3.0.0.RELEASE, I have two tests that fail with :

```
Index name for class java.lang.String name rel: false idx: true must differ from the default name: BesoinNode
```

In the `BesoinNode` class, I previously used `@Indexed(indexName = "indexOfNeeds")` but removed the `indexName` because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084251/1528942. Now my index declaration is simply :

```java
@Indexed
private String name;
```

The failing test code is :

```java
@Test
public final void t02_TestBesoinDAORetrieve() {
    // We create a new object in the datastore
    Besoin need1 = needDAO.create(new BesoinNode("t02 need"));
    assertEquals(new Long(1), needDAO.count());

    // We retrieve the object from the datastore using its id
    Besoin need1bis = needDAO.retrieveById(need1.getId());
    assertEquals(need1, need1bis);
    assertEquals(need1.getId(), need1bis.getId());
    assertEquals(need1.getName(), need1bis.getName());

    // We retrieve the object from the datastore using its name
    Besoin need1ter = needDAO.retrieveByName(need1.getName());
    assertEquals(need1, need1ter);
    assertEquals(need1.getId(), need1ter.getId());
    assertEquals(need1.getName(), need1ter.getName());
}
```

The test succeeds if I comment out the call to `retrieveByName`. Code is below:

```java
@Override
public Besoin retrieveByName(String name) {
    return repository.findByPropertyValue("name", name);
}
```

How can I rewrite my `retrieveByName` method to solve the error? Thanks!

***Note*** : while this may no be related to the problem, I see in the [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/api/index.html?index-all.html) that `IndexRepository#findByPropertyValue(String, Object)` is deprecated. Only `AbstractGraphRepository#findByPropertyValue(String, Object)` is **not** deprecated. The problem is that my repository extends `GraphRepository` and that `GraphRepository` extends `IndexRepository`, something I have no control over.

***Note 2*** : Using `@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.SIMPLE)` makes the test succeed. But this toggles the old index system (not the new one which is label-based).

Comment: Could you raise an JIRA issue for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done : https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-437